# Char parameter in function is null or empty in C

Tags: c, function, char, scanf, do-while

I'm currently learning `c`, then I'm playing with functions and data types, specifically in this case `char[]`'s.

The following code I've written declares a function called `verifyMessage()` and receives two parameters, `name` and `gender`.

When I execute the function, I pass the two parameters that the user enters through the console, but when I print the `name` it doesn't print anything.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i = 0;
    double controlNumber = 21200164;
    double number = 0;
    char name[50];
    char gender[1];
    int attempts = 5;
    int aux = 0;

    do {
        printf("Introduzca el numero de control: ");
        scanf("%lf", &number);
        if (controlNumber == number) {
            printf("\nWrite your name: ");
            scanf("%s", name);
            printf("\nWrite your gender (M/F): ");
            scanf("%s", gender);
            verifyMessage(name, gender);
            break;
        } else {
            i++;
        }
    } while (i < attempts);

    return 0;
}

void verifyMessage(char name[50], char gender[1]) {
    if ('M' == gender[0]) {
        printf("\n\Name: %s", name);//Here doesn´t print the name
        printf("\nMen");
    } else if ('F' == gender[0]) {
         printf("\nWoman");
    } else {
        printf("\nInvalid gender");
    }
}
```

Comment: An array of length 1 is kind of pointless. Don't even bother.

Comment: `char gender[1];` needs to be at least `char gender[2];`. Strings in C have a NUL terminator. So a single letter string requires two chars to store. You currently have a buffer overflow and hence undefined behaviour.

Comment: An alternative is to use `char gender;` instead of an array.

Comment: @Barmar ... and `scanf(" %c", &gender);` instead of `scanf("%s", gender);`

Comment: @MikeCAT I was leaving that as an exercise for the student....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `char gender[1];` with `%s` is dangerous because `gender` has room for only one element, so it can accept only strings upto zero characters (the only room will be occupied by terminating null-character)

On the other hand, `%s` will read positive-length strings (it cannot read strings with zero characters), so it will cause out-of-range access on successful read.

Allocate enough elements and set the maximum length to read (upto the number of elements minis one for terminating null-character) to avoid buffer overrun.

```
char name[50];
char gender[2];

/* ... */

printf("\nWrite your name: ");
scanf("%49s", name);
printf("\nWrite your gender (M/F): ");
scanf("%1s", gender);
```

Checking results (return values) of `scanf()` to check if they successfully read desired things will improve your code more.

Comment: Thanks for you kind help, I completly forgot the tratament of `char`'s in `c`.